# Issue with Open file from device Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am using this code to open file from device Andriod & IOS. Its working with android but not working with IOS

FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();

String fileName = fs.getAppHomePath()+FileName;

Util.downloadUrlToFile(FullURL, fileName, true);

Display.getInstance().execute(fileName);

Please advice
Thanks

Comment: Does fileName have an extension? What is that extension? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: The our app is HR and the employee can upload the file with extension as pdf or image or docx, and saved to the server , this file opened from android and internet browsers. the employee after uploaded his file as sick leave to approved from managers its not open with IOS. may security issue from IOS!!!

Comment: PDF used to work so if that stopped working this is a regression https://www.codenameone.com/blog/open-file-rendering.html if it doesn't work please file an issue with the exact OS version so we can track that down